# Visual Studios 2013 - C++ Linker Error with openCV 3.0 Libs

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, linker, opencv3.0

Their is a problem with the Linker for C++ in my Visual Studios 2013 on Windows 8. I want to use openCV 3.0 with my Visual Studios. All links inside the code will be used normal and IntelliSense recognize the datamembers. But if I want to compile the programm Visual Studios give me following errors:

> Fehler    1   error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""private: char * __thiscall cv::String::allocate(unsigned int)" (?allocate@String@cv@@AAEPADI@Z)" in Funktion ""public: __thiscall cv::String::String(char const *)" (??0String@cv@@QAE@PBD@Z)".  C:\Users\Marc\Documents\Workspaces\C++_VS\OpenCV_Test\OpenCV_Test\main.obj  OpenCV_Test
>   Fehler  2   error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""private: void __thiscall cv::String::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@String@cv@@AAEXXZ)" in Funktion ""public: __thiscall cv::String::~String(void)" (??1String@cv@@QAE@XZ)". C:\Users\Marc\Documents\Workspaces\C++_VS\OpenCV_Test\OpenCV_Test\main.obj  OpenCV_Test
>   Fehler  3   error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: __thiscall cv::CommandLineParser::CommandLineParser(int,char const * const * const,class cv::String const &)" (??0CommandLineParser@cv@@QAE@HQBQBDABVString@1@@Z)" in Funktion "_main".  C:\Users\Marc\Documents\Workspaces\C++_VS\OpenCV_Test\OpenCV_Test\main.obj  OpenCV_Test
>   Fehler  4   error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: __thiscall cv::CommandLineParser::~CommandLineParser(void)" (??1CommandLineParser@cv@@QAE@XZ)" in Funktion "_main".  C:\Users\Marc\Documents\Workspaces\C++_VS\OpenCV_Test\OpenCV_Test\main.obj  OpenCV_Test
>   Fehler  5   error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""protected: void __thiscall cv::CommandLineParser::getByName(class cv::String const &,bool,int,void *)const " (?getByName@CommandLineParser@cv@@IBEXABVString@2@_NHPAX@Z)" in Funktion ""public: class cv::String __thiscall cv::CommandLineParser::get(class cv::String const &,bool)const " (??$get@VString@cv@@@CommandLineParser@cv@@QBE?AVString@1@ABV21@_N@Z)".   C:\Users\Marc\Documents\Workspaces\C++_VS\OpenCV_Test\OpenCV_Test\main.obj  OpenCV_Test
>   Fehler  6   error LNK1120: 5 nicht aufgelöste Externe   C:\Users\Marc\Documents\Workspaces\C++_VS\OpenCV_Test\Debug\OpenCV_Test.exe 1   1   OpenCV_Test

I installed openCV with the following guide: http://www.minlabz.com/how-to-install-opencv-3-0-0-on-windows-7-and-configure-with-visual-studio-2014/

Here is the little code that I used to test if the openCV dependencies work:

```
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    const char* keyMap;
    //Standard image that will be used if dont exist arguments
    keyMap = "{path     |   |  }";

    //Reading the Callingarguments
    CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, keyMap);
    String filename = parser.get<String>("path");
}
```

I hope I don't forgot something simple.

Comment: Are there more than 2 libs in `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib`?

Comment: I could use the _staticlib_ folder in openCV and add all the libraries to the _Additional Dependencies_ from there. I don't tested it yet. But what is the difference between the normal **lib** and the **staticlib** folder from opencv?

Comment: I think in this case the linking problem would be essentially the same for static opencv or dll. Since with dll you still need to link to import libraries.

Comment: There a only 4 libs: _opecv_ts300.lib_, _opecv_ts300d.lib_, _opecv_world300.lib_ and _opecv_ts300d.lib_.

Comment: I am wrong then.. This is a change from opencv 2.X.X. I deleted my first comment as a result.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you remove that line and, for example, you define a cv::Mat? I have seen around people having troubles specifically with cv::String because of some libC++ problems.

Comment: I will try it after a slept a bit. But the error didn't show up for the String class alone. It also appears on the _CommandLineParser_ class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The porblem is solved now.

I re-extract opencv and followed the steps of the following two links:

[Install OpenCV 3.0 on Windows 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcFtefHEEII)

[Create an Visual Studio (2013) Project with openCV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHX3MLzwF6Q)

Answer (score 0):

When you installed the OpenCV 3 with visual studio 2013 and cmake , you will find the dlls in

`\opencv\msvc\bin\Release` for the release mode and the `include` in `\opencv\build\include`, therefore invoke the command prompt and type

```
cl /EHsc main.cpp /Fetest.exe /I D:\CPP_Libraries\opencv_3.0.0\build\include /link /LIBPATH:D:\CPP_Libraries\opencv_3.0.0\msvc\lib\Release opencv_core300.lib
```

with this sample

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>



int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    std::cout << "\n%%( Random Generator )%%\n"; 
    cv::Mat G = cv::Mat::ones(4,4, CV_64FC1);
    cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::zeros(1,1, CV_64FC1);
    cv::Mat s = cv::Mat::ones(1,1, CV_64FC1);
    std::cout << G << std::endl;
    cv::randn(G, m, s);
    std::cout << G << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: I don't got the folder `\opencv\msvc\bin\Release`. So I think that I need to create it through cmake but I don't know how and where.

Comment: ***So I think that I need to create it through cmake but I don't know how and where.*** That was if you built opencv from source using CMake and installed from the INSTALL target  to `\opencv\msvc`

Comment: I don't installed openCV. I only extracted the files like in the guide that I linked. So I also never used cmake on openCV files.

Comment: @Steno, why not. it is very simple. Do you want the steps??

Comment: The problem is solved now, but I don't really know how the problem diappered. I only tested another code (from openCV Website) and then it worked. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Having experienced very similar compilation error messages than those shown in the original post, I followed the thorough links above (Install OpenCV 3.0 on Windows 8, Create an Visual Studio (2013) Project with openCV).

This did not solve the compilation errors though.

What worked for me was to change the OPENCV_DIR environment variable to point to the x86 build of openCV instead of the x64 build.

Answer (score -1):

If you had compiled opencv in x64 environment, I strongly recommend you to change x64 platform in Configuration Manager(Visual studio). I fixed same problem like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8DOw.jpg)